# Custom Rules -- how to implement in web-based tool?

Tags: architecture

So I am building a web based replacement for a forecasting tool built using excel.

For the most part, the line items are simple -- X units of Y, at unit cost Z equals this line item cost.

However, for an unavoidable handful of types of items, the rules are more complex (two types of items taken together, integer divided by six, times a cost item, to get one -- etc.). Ultimately, these rules may change over time -- in fact one of the goals of redoing the tool is to make it easy for finance to "tweak" the formulas.

So here's my question: is there an architecture or design pattern best suited to this? I could store "rules" as javascript that I eval to do calculations, but this seems hacky and insecure. However, I can't come up with a better solution that allows some "free form" logic in a basically sandboxed environment.

Keep in mind that this is (right now) a very small tool, so buying some big, expensive business intelligence tool is a non-starter.

Comment: Are these rules or expressions? Are you trying to constrain manual inputs or you are trying to calculate some field values dynamically? How do you expect these rules to be maintained? Will they be maintained through a DSL or built using a UI? If you want to rely on JavaScript expressions while staying safe you may use an existing JavaScript parser to verify that the expression is safe before executing it. You could also build your own DSL, parse it and transform it into a JavaScript expression that can be executed or create your own runtime.

Comment: Some existing libraries may help such as https://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/ or http://mathjs.org/ . If you are more looking towards constraining inputs you may look at the [Specification pattern](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf).